# Is a non-fractal, continuous curve made of tiny line segments?

Tags: derivatives, real-numbers, curves, fractals, infinitesimals

**EDIT:** This question was in-part made unclear by my misconception of the hyperreals not being dense, since I thought there were no numbers between zero and consecutive infinitesimals
($0, 1/\infty, 2/\infty, ...$). Furthermore, it was a question based on an assumption begging more questions. My question has now deferred to the question of that assumption.

---

I believe the following is an account of all non-fractal, continuous curves on the Cartesian plane between $a$ and $b$. Such curves can be though of as the limit, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, of linearly interpolating more and more points along the curve, where $n$ is the number of **sampled points.** This shrinks the line segments between the points down to points, eventually leaving us with a continuous string of points.

Now, in a curve $C$ made by linearly interpolating between some set of points, the following property holds:

$$\forall p \in C, \exists q \in C, \ \text{s.t}. \overline{pq} \in C 
 \tag 1$$

I might be abusing notation here, but in English, I am simply saying the for all points on such a curve, there must exist another point, such that the curve $C$ between $p$ and $q$ is a straight line. This is obviously true for a curve made by linearly interpolating between some set of points. However, does this property extend to continuous, non-fractal curves, given the above account?

You might say that: $$\lim_{q \rightarrow p} p-q = 0$$

But if that were applicable in this context, it would mean that one would be sampling all the points in the curve in order to replicate it. However, as we approach the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the number of points between the sampled points shrinks to one, not zero. I mean, you cannot linearly interpolate between a point and itself? You don't need to at least. If you agree with the account given at the beginning of this post, then you agree as we approach the limit, the line segments between the points shrinks **towards** single points, not zero points. Perhaps for the real numbers, this is the same. For the hyperreals and above, it would not be, since among them you have the infinitesimals.

---

So, that is my question. Is the property $(1)$ true for continuous, non-fractal curves in $\Bbb R^2$? And if not, is it perhaps true for such curves in $^*\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: I don't understand the question at all.  What are "adjacent points"?

Comment: @XanderHenderson See my edit.

Comment: Continuous curves are not necessarily differentiable. Fractals are usually not differentiable. Hyperreals are a completely separate issue.

Comment: No, I still have no idea what you are talking about.  Perhaps you could give an explicit example to demonstrate this notion of "adjacent points in the hyperreal plane"?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Two adjacent points in the hyperreal plane would be $(0,0)$ and $(0,1/\infty)$.

Comment: I don't see how those two numbers are adjacent.  The hyperreals form an ordered field, no?  Multiplication and the ordering play nice together, so if $x$ and $y$ are hyperreal numbers, then $\frac{1}{2}(x+y)$ is also a hyperreal number, and sits between $x$ and $y$ in the ordering, yes?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Are you saying the hyperreals are not dense? I thought I read they were. I mean, what is the point of infinitesimals if not to be the units of the hyperreal number line? I thought the hyperreals were an attempt at uniting continuity with non-density.

Comment: @user110391 I think I just asserted that the hyperreals *are* dense, in the sense that there are always more hyperreals between any two chosen hyperreals.  And I don't know what you mean by "uniting continuity with non-density".

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yeah I mis-typed. I was asking for confirmation on whether  you were saying that the hyperreals are dense (which I thought they weren't). Now that you have confirmed this is what you are saying, I will simplify my previous question: what is the point of infinitesimals? No infinitesimal represents the smallest possible distance between one point and another, since smaller infinitesimals exist. So, what's the point of postulating them?

Comment: You might try reading Abraham Robinson's *Nonstandard Analysis*.  I would expect that Robinson might argue that thinking infinitesimally makes much of analysis easier to explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147463/discussion-between-user110391-and-xander-henderson).

Comment: @user110391, your property (1) states that for every point $p$, there is a straight line interval $pq$ contained in the curve.  But this isn't even true for the ordinary round circle.  Perhaps what inspired your question is the classical idea found in the 17th century that a circle is an infinite-sided polygon.  But this is only true in approximation.

Comment: @MikhailKatz There is definitely some inspiration from such ideas. And I know that as the limit is approached, it is only an approximation. But surely, if the limit was reached, it would be the curve?

Answer (score 1):

What can be shown is that every continuous curve can be approximated (to within an infinitesimal) by an internal curve consisting of infinitesimal line segments.  But the curve itself cannot be such a infinite-sided polygon if you work in the traditional setting of classical logic.  Something like that can be achieved in Synthetic Differential Geometry where you need to work in a category-theoretic framework and use intuitionistic logic; see Bell's book.

Comment: Approximated to within an infinitesimal would, for real numbers, mean they are identical, since infinitesimals are not among the reals? If not that, perhaps *approximated to within an infinitesimal* is rather just meaningless when talking about the reals?

Comment: Also, perhaps this on-going discussion is of any help in understanding my confusion: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147463/discussion-between-user110391-and-xander-henderson

Comment: The approximation of course takes place in the hyperreals (note that I observed that the approximation is an *internal* curve), which were mentioned in your *question*.

Comment: But would the process I described be an approximation within the reals, and if so, to what degree would it be an approximation? Also, what is an internal curve?

Comment: One can certainly approximate a continuous curve by a polygon, but in the limit what you get back is the curve itself, which may not contain any line segments.  For the *internal* notion in infinitesimal analysis see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_set) and the Goldblatt reference cited there.